# Not able to open http://localhost:8000/ but opening in public ip ngnix Django

Tags: python, django, nginx

I am new to Python Django. I am working on a Django project using Ubuntu, nginx and python, Django.

Question is that :
I am able to open the application with URL name in browser like: http://example.com . But the application is NOT opening locally in server with localhost:8000  or public-ip:8000, below is the output of related commands:

```
$ wget -O- http://localhost:8000
--2017-01-17 13:15:30--  localhost:8000
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 NOT FOUND
2017-01-17 13:15:30 ERROR 404: NOT FOUND.

$ netstat -lan | grep 8000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

$ elinks http://  localhost:8000
                                                                                                                                                    Page not found at /
                                                          Page not found (404)

Request Method: GET
Request URL:   http://  localhost:8000/
Raised by:    mainpages.views.index

   No tenant for hostname "localhost"

   You're seeing this error because¤you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you using `django-tennant`?...

Answer (score 1):

this is because you are using tenant_schema in your application. and you are running your application without creating a tenant. so the django is saying you to create a tenant first.

That is:
after making use of

> python manage.pt makemigrations and migrate

command 
post data into your tenant model table that you have created using

> python manage.py shell

python shell will prompt. here import your tenant model class. and pass data into it.
ex

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from xyz_app.models import Client
>>>
>>> Client(domain_url='energy.mystupidurl.com', schema_name='public', name='public', paid_until = '2099-12-31', on_trial =False).save()
```

here **Client** is tenant here. and

> domain_url, schema_name, pain_untill, and on_trial

are variable of the class

> Client

Answer (score 1):

This is the steps I followed after configure shared and tenant apps:

```
SHARED_APPS = [
    'tenant_schemas',  # mandatory
    'empresas',  # you must list the app where your tenant model resides in

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'import_export',
    'bootstrap4',
    'usuarios',

]

TENANT_APPS = [
    'app',
    'productos',
    'ventas',
    'medidas',
    # 'app.apps.AppConfig',
    # 'usuarios.apps.UsuariosConfig',
    # 'productos.apps.ProductosConfig',
    # 'ventas.apps.VentasConfig',
    # 'medidas.apps.MedidasConfig',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = list(SHARED_APPS) + [app for app in TENANT_APPS if app not in SHARED_APPS]

TENANT_MODEL = "empresas.Empresa" # app.Model
TENANT_DOMAIN_MODEL = "empresas.Domain" # app.Model

SITE_ID = 1
```

- Delete mi postgres schemas
- Create public schema
- Delete all migrations in all apps
- Create a file with the admin/public and 2 tenants at empresas app. Just to place the code backup:

```
    from empresas.models import Empresa
    tenant = Empresa(domain_url = 'kinetfood.local',
                    schema_name = 'public',
                    nombre = 'Kirios Net',
                    nro_mesas = '4',
                    )
    tenant.save()

    tenant = Empresa(domain_url = 'titu.kinetfood.local',
                    schema_name = 'titu',
                    nombre = 'Titu Cocktail Xpress',
                    nro_mesas = '4',
                    )
    tenant.save()

    tenant = Empresa(domain_url = 'lasalva.kinetfood.local',
                    schema_name = 'lasalva',
                    nombre = 'La Salva burguer',
                    nro_mesas = '10',
                    )
    tenant.save()
```

- Duplicate the file kinetfood/urls.py and rename the copy to: public_urls.py
- Add to settings `PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URL_CONF = 'kinetfoood.public_urls'`
- Run `python manage.py makemigrations`
- Run `python manage.py migrate_schemas --shared`
- Run `python .\manage.py shell` and paste the create_tenant script, double Enter.
- Set the same host dirs at: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc on Windows

```
    # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    #   127.0.0.1       localhost
    #   ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
    ::1             localhost

    127.0.0.1       kinetfood.local
    127.0.0.1       titu.kinetfood.local
    127.0.0.1       lasalva.kinetfood.local
```

- Run `python .\manage.py runserver`
- Put the url domain in browser `http://titu.kinetfood.local:8000/`
- Voilá

I hope this helps you.

Comment: What would I need to do not to get "No tenant for `kinetfood.local`" at `kinetfood.local:8000` ?

Comment: It means you need to create a tenant. Open '''python manage.py shell'' and paste the code to create a tenant. Then postgres will create a new schema with the public tenant.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs for `django-tennant-schemas`](http://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) (which I presume you're using) it states:

> If the hostname in the request does not match a valid tenant domain_url, a HTTP 404 Not Found will be returned. )

So simply make a tenant that you can use for your localhost.

Comment: Thanks Sayse.. I will go through the given link to add the new tanent for local host and will update the result..